# Controlling the number of CPUs used by registerDoParallel

Tags: r, doparallel, rparallel

I have recently inherited a legacy R script that at some point trains a gradient boost model with a large regression matrix. This task is parallelised using the `doParallel::registerDoParallel` function. Originally, the script started the parallel back end with:

```
cl = makeCluster(10)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(c)
```

The workstation has 12 CPU and 28 GB of RAM. The regression matrix being just over 2 GB, I thought this set up would be manageable, however, it would launch dozens of sub-processes, exhausting the memory and crashing R in a few seconds. Eventually I understood that on Linux, a more predictable set up can be achieved by using the `cores` parameter:

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores = 1)
```

Where `cores` is actually the number of sub-processes per CPU, i.e., with `cores = 2` it launches 24 sub-process in this 12 CPU architecture. The problem is that with such a large regression matrix, even 12 sub-processes is too much.

How can the number of sub-processes launched by `registerDoParallel` be restricted to, say, 8? Would it help using a different parallelisation library?

**Update**: To ascertain the memory required by each sub-process, I ran the script without starting a cluster or using `registerDoParallel`; still  ,12 back end sub-processes were spawned. The culprit is the [`caret::train`](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html)  function,  it seems to be managing parallelisation without oversight. I opened [a new issue at GitHub](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/870) asking for instructions on how to limit the resources used by this function.